# How to determine which size of surface mount resistor for an ADMP441

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, pcb-assembly

I'm relatively new to reflow surface mount soldering and am unfamiliar with the various sizes of components.

The PCB design I ordered is here:
https://oshpark.com/shared_projects/ypqAU3CH

But I don't see any reference to which size components I should order to fit the design.  (ie 0402 0603 0805 1206)  In this case, I suspect that the correct size is 0603...but I don't want to order parts on an educated guess.

How can I determine the correct size of components to order for any given board design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the `*.brd` file and open it in Eagle, then look at the footprint properties for the footprint specifier.

In this board, it appears that the two SMT passives are 0603.

To generalize this answer, if you are not able to download the board files (say, all you have is Gerbers), then you can open the Gerbers in a Gerber viewer, measure the distance between pads, and determine which component size the board uses. However, it is generally a bad idea to try to populate and use a board for which you do not have a schematic or board files for.

Answer (score 0):

Holes for goldpins are very good reference dimension on this board (standard 2,54mm pitch between pins). Also note that pads for passive components are long (in longer axis of component), so they look like some kind of universal pads. Additionally there is plenty of free space around them.

To sum up, every size from 0603 to 1206 will be good for that PCB. There is a rule of thumb that 0402 elements almost always fits in 0603 pads, 0603 in 0805, 0805 in 1206 and so on.